# How can i output a string in a label on page?

Tags: php

I am trying want to ouput a string ,stored in a variabel, in a label on a page when i click on a button.
But i can't find out how. Still a beginner.

```
<form action="Test.php" method="post">
Output text: <input type="label" name="word" />
<input type="submit" method="submit" value="Print!" />
</form>
<?php
$word = "test";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//something that gives the label value $word//
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't do this when you click on a button. PHP is a server-side language, meaning that it is done running before the user ever sees it. You might want to look into AJAX.

Comment: You have to show us your form! But if you watch a basic php tutorial you would learn that on the way

Comment: What label? Is your question about PHP or about the HTML code that it should generate?

Comment: `method="submit"` in your submit input is invalid (technically speaking, method belongs in form). Plus, you need to give it a name attribute. `It=submit button`. You also need named attributes for all your form elements and assign POST variables in regards to the input(s).

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies

Comment: why you have taken input `type='label'`?

Comment: @IvoryNL I have posted an answer for you to look at below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27680098/1415724 along with a few explanations in regards to your present code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

Let me outline them.

- Your submit input should have a name attribute, since your conditional statement is based on it `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){...}`, something I've modified to check if the input is not left empty, using PHP's [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.
- The input type you have for your "Output text" is invalid, it should be `type="text"` and not `type="label"`, there is no `type="label"`.
- `method="submit"` for your submit button is invalid for a few reasons. Method belongs in `<form>` and there is no `method="submit"`.
- You then need to assign a POST variable from the input:

such as:

```
$word = $_POST['word'];
```

Plus, from what looks to me that you're executing the entire code from within the same page, you can just do `action=""`, unless your code is set in 2 seperate files.

*In regards to what you want to achieve:* You can then echo the input (if one was entered) using a [**ternary operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and giving it (the input) a value.

I.e.:

```
value="<?php echo isset($_POST['word']) ? $_POST['word']: '' ?>"
```

Here:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Output text: <input type="text" name="word" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['word']) ? $_POST['word']: '' ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print!" />
</form>
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['word']) )
{
$word = $_POST['word'];
echo $word;
}
?>
```

If you want to use a "[**label**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label)" for your input, then use:

```
<label for="word">Output text:  
<input type="text" name="word" />
</label>
```

---

You should also guard against XSS attacks (Cross-side scripting) using:

- http://php.net/strip_tags
- http://php.net/htmlentities
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

I.e.:

```
$word = strip_tags($_POST['word']);
$word = htmlentities($_POST['word']);
$word = htmlspecialchars($_POST['word']);
```

A few articles you can read on XSS:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
<form action="Test.php" method="post">
Output text: <input type="label" name="word" value ="<?php echo isset($label['data'])?$label['data']: '' ?>" />
<input type="submit" method="submit" value="Print!" />
</form>
<?php
$word = "test";
$label = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//something that gives the label value $word//
   $label['data'] = $word;
}
?>
```

This should work

Regards
Ahmad rabbani

Comment: Look over the OP's code again, *very carefully* and the comments under it also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your input element has `type = label`, it doesn't mean anything. Change it to `type=text`

And you are submitting value but not printing it. So in input field you have to print it also.

Look below code.

```
<?php
$word = "test";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // whatever you do with $word
}
?>
<form action="Test.php" method="post">
Output text: <input type="text" name="word" value="<?php echo $word; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print!" />
</form>
```

### UPDATE

One more thing I forgot to mention that you are submitting form to Test.php and printing this to file, if this file's name is `Test.php` then not an issue, other wise leave `action` property blank, so it submit data to itself.

`method = submit` there is nothing like this. you can set button name to submit, like `name= "submit"`.